# mongoose - delete array element of a document, selecting only one object from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck with this case, can't guess whats the way of doing a selective pull of an element from an array with no keys.

I have a collection organized like in this example and mapped onto mongoose:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  site: { type: String, required: true },
  employees: { type: Array, required: true}
}
```

employees is an array that contains a variable number of employees objects with no order, it is shaped like that:

```
employees: [
    {
        "name" : "xxx",
        "surname" : "yyy",
        "email" : "email@address.com",
        
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

I usually access this data easilly with an aggregate query to shape it in the way I need, but, I am unable to delete one employee by selecting it.

I would like to delete a whole employee object by selecting it using it's email address as I would do an aggregate search, but then deleting it.

```
AccessList.aggregate([
      { '$match': id},
      { '$unwind': '$employees' },
      { '$match': email}])
///then delete this whole object returned
```

my best try so far, is with a updateOne, but of course, it returns an error:

```
AccessList.updateOne( {'id': request.params.date}, { $pullAll: {'employees.email': request.params.email } } )
```

> "$pullAll requires an array argument but was given a null"

it is clearly wrong, but can't think of a better way, any clues?

thanks!

Comment: is your request.params.email an array?

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/

Comment: no, is one element of the array I use for locating the correct array element

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, this is what you need to start the ball rolling ...

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uv8ERuZ_RF3

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  id: 1
},
{
  $pull: {
    employee: {
      email: "2@address.com"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This will only remove the `email` field from the `employee` object, it won't remove the entire `employee` object

Comment: @rantao you sure?

Comment: searching for 'id' finds the correct bucket, then i need to point to the n element in the vector and delete it, but I don't know the index. I can just search by value inside the object, like the email.

Comment: should it be a 2 stages process? like 1: getting the array and defining the index number 2: pulling the array